# How to select Price in the Pricing and Availability section in the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to publish my app in App Store. But in the Pricing and Availability section i can not choose any price. There is not the price list. Without choosing any price i can not publsih the app. What should i do? Is this a bug?[image]

Comment: Have you completed all of the required tax and banking forms and the paid applications agreement?

Comment: i have completed all of the required forms. But price list is not showing. I can not select price